# How do I implement this type of scrolling angular material sidenav?

Tags: angular, nav, angular-material2

I am trying to build a nav menu that follows as you scroll.

Like this one:
From the Angular Material website: 
https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview

Here is a snippet of what I want to build:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq1Gn.png

Does Angular Material already have a component like this? Is it called something different?

Answer (score 2):

You can check out how the documentation site does it by viewing the [source code](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io).

The respective files are:

- [`table-of-contents.ts`](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/master/src/app/shared/table-of-contents/table-of-contents.ts) and [`table-of-contents.html`](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/master/src/app/shared/table-of-contents/table-of-contents.html)
- [`component-viewer.html`](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/master/src/app/pages/guide-viewer/component-viewer.html) and  (placement of the `table-of-contents` component)
- [`component-viewer.scss`](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/master/src/app/pages/component-viewer/component-viewer.scss) (the styling for the `table-of-contents` on the component overview)